# Unable to upgrade sitecore nuget 8. 2 to 9.0.1

Tags: upgrade

Goal is to upgrade our sitecore VS solution from 8.2 update 1 to sitecore 9 update 1.

Thought this would be easier but I keep getting this error below when trying to upgrade my sitecore nuget packages from 8.2 update 1 to sitecore 9.0 update 1.

> Package 'Sitecore.Abstractions.9.0.171219' does not exist in folder
>   'C:\Work\source\repo\sitecore9poc\packages'
>
> Could not install package 'Sitecore.Abstractions 9.0.171219'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   ========== Finished ==========

I tried updating the Target Framework from 4.5 to 4.6 and same issue.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76644/discussion-on-question-by-nil-pun-unable-to-upgrade-sitecore-nuget-8-2-to-9-0-1).

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be related to the .net version you are targetting on your projects. Sitecore 9 requires .Net 4.6.2 or 4.7. It seems like one or some of your projects are using 4.5.2.

Compatibility table reference: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps that worked for me using VS 2017:

1. Upgrade .Net 4.6.2 or 4.7
2. If you get this error below then manually remove System.Net.Http reference and Install-Package System.Net.Http -Version 4.0.0

> "Unable to find a version of 'System.Net.Http' that is compatible.."

3. Make code change below if you are using Tracker.Current.Session.Identify.

> Replace Tracker.Current.Session.Identify with
>   Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs

4. Use solution on link below if you face this

> error "ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755274/visual-studio-2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4/49078929#49078929